# jQuery use returned JSON array outside of function using post

Tags: jquery, arrays, post, scope

I am sure I am missing something obvious, but whatever it is I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what I have

```
var warr = new Array();

$('#step3next').click(function() {
    $.post('AJAX_GetGameWords.asp',function(data) {
        fw(data.warray);
    },"json");

    $('.vardisplay3').append(warr+'');
});

function fw(x) {
    warr = [x]; 
}
```

Ultimately what I am wanting is to be able to use the warr array anywhere.

If I put the `$('.vardisplay3').append(warr+'');`  just under fw(data.warray);  then it works just fine and displays in .vardisplay3, but with where it is now, it doesn't display anything.

I would think since warr is set as global, it would work, but I am obviously missing a scope issue or something.

Can anyone explain what is going on and how can I have the ability to use the warr array anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: It's not a scoping issue, it's a timing issue -- the `$.post` callback function doesn't run until *at least* after the current function call stack is cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a scope issue, it's an order of execution issue.  `.post()` is *asynchronous*, so this line of code:

```
$('.vardisplay3').append(warr+'');
```

is being executed *before* this line of code:

```
fw(data.warray);
```

The scope is fine, but if you want something to happen in response to an asynchronous AJAX call (such as appending a returned value) then it needs to be invoked from the call-back function of that AJAX call.  Otherwise it'll execute before the AJAX call is finished and it won't have any data to use.

Answer (score 2):

post is asynchronous.

you need to use the success callback if you want to use the returned data

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the  **$.post** with an **ajax** call like this it will be callback your data easily and prevent your this issue...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "AJAX_GetGameWords.asp",
  data: "",
  async: false,
  success: function(t){
    alert(t);// You can call your function HERE
  }
});
```